# "no coprocess" error when using read

Tags: bash, shell-script, read

I have a bash script that is named `reader`. It reads user input:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "What is your name?" username
echo "Hello, ${username}"
```

Running the script by `source reader` (EDIT: from the zsh shell), I get the error `reader:read:2: -p: no coprocess`. It doesn't give this error when I run it as `./reader`.

Other `read` options do not produce this error. For example, I could have done:

```
#/bin/bash
echo -n "What is your name?"
read username
echo "Hello, ${username}"
```

Where does the no coprocess error come from? What does it mean? And what should I do about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `source`, it's the current shell that reads the file, not the shell mentioned on the `#!` line.  And I assume that your shell is either `zsh` or `ksh93` which uses `read -p` to read from a co-process.

An example of that in `ksh93`:

```
cat /etc/passwd |&

while IFS=":" read -p user rest; do
    printf 'There is a user called %s\n' "$user"
done
```

To run *your* script, either explicitly mention the interpreter:

```
$ bash script.sh
```

... or make the script executable and run it:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

To get `read` to use a custom prompt in both `zsh` and `ksh93`:

```
read username"?What's you name? " 
printf 'Hello %s!\n' "$username"
```

Comment: Actually, I was using the zsh shell. I edited my question to show this crucial fact. I found that zsh also uses `-p` to read from a coprocess.

Comment: @Flux, ah, yes that makes sense too.

Comment: @Flux I've updated the answer a tiny bit, but also marked the question as a duplicate. The main issue was the sourcing of the script in any case.